# Background Worker Call Method or something

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I have a method/procedure which works well, however it takes ages to do its thing so I want to move it into a background worker so people can still use the app.

Here is the code. (I cut down as much as I could)

```
public partial class NetworkInformation : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public NetworkInformation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Discovery();
        }
        public void Discovery()
        {
            GetIcon Icon = new GetIcon();
            BitmapImage IconOfComputer = null;
            List<DiscoveredComputer> NetworkedComputers = new List<DiscoveredComputer>();
            DirectoryEntry Discover = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://Workgroup");
            BitmapImage On = Icon.LoadIcon(@"/Images/Icons/ComputerOn.ico");
            BitmapImage Off = Icon.LoadIcon(@"/Images/Icons/ComputerOff.ico");
            foreach (DirectoryEntry Node in Discover.Children)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Node.Properties.Count > 0)
                    {
                        IconOfComputer = On;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    IconOfComputer = Off;
                }
                if (Node.Name != "Schema") { NetworkedComputers.Add(new DiscoveredComputer { Image = IconOfComputer, ComputerName = Node.Name, MyToolTip = "Node Type = " + Node.SchemaEntry.Name }); }
            }
            ListView_LocalComputers.ItemsSource = NetworkedComputers;
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

    public class DiscoveredComputer : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _ComputerName;
        public string ComputerName
        {
            get { return _ComputerName; }
            set
            {
                _ComputerName = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ComputerName");
            }
        }
        private BitmapImage _Image;
        public BitmapImage Image { 
            get { return _Image; }
            set
            { 
                _Image = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Image");
            }
        }
        private String _MyToolTip;
        public String MyToolTip
        {
            get { return _MyToolTip; }
            set
            {
                _MyToolTip = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ToolTip");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
    public class GetIcon
    {
        public BitmapImage IconStorage { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage LoadIcon(String IconPath)
        {
            BitmapImage GeneratedIcon = new BitmapImage();
            GeneratedIcon.BeginInit();
            GeneratedIcon.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,," + IconPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            GeneratedIcon.EndInit();
            IconStorage = GeneratedIcon;
            return GeneratedIcon;
        }
    }
}
```

This all works awesomely, somehow...

Here is the code I:developed for my background worker

```
 public partial class MyBackgroundWorker : UserControl
    {
        WorkerData BGW;
        public MyBackgroundWorker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BGW = new WorkerData();

            #region Workers Events
            BGW.ThisWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Workers_DoWork);
            BGW.ThisWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(Workers_Progress);
            BGW.ThisWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Workers_Completed);
            BGW.ThisWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            BGW.ThisWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            #endregion


        }
        public void RibbonButton_EventClickStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BGW.ThisWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        public void UserForm_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
        public void RibbonButton_EventClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BGW.ThisWorker.CancelAsync();
        }
        public void Workers_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public void Workers_Progress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            BGW.ThisWorkersProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        public void Workers_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled) { BGW.ThisWorkersResult = "Cancelled By User"; }
            else if (e.Error != null) { BGW.ThisWorkersResult = "Error Encountered: " + e.Error.Message; }
            else
            {
                BGW.ThisWorkersResult = "Task Completed Successfully";
                BGW.WorkersReturnObject = e.Result;
            }
        }
    }
    public class WorkerData
    {
        public BackgroundWorker ThisWorker { get; set; }
        public int ThisWorkersProgress { get; set; }
        public string ThisWorkersResult { get; set; }
        public object WorkersReturnObject { get; set; }
        public object ThisWorkersJob { get; set; }

        public WorkerData()
        {
            ThisWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        }
    }
```

So how do I get my background worker to run the Discovery method I have created?

Answer (score 3):

You need to do your work in the `DoWork` event handler.

Comment: @NewBee: By writing code in your `Workers_DoWork`.  I'm not sure what you don't understand.

Comment: if i do that i cannot use my background worker information for other methods i have. do i have to write a background worker for each one ?

Comment: Yes.  Consider using `await Task.Run()` instead; it's much easier to use.  Read http://blog.slaks.net/2013-10-11/threads-vs-tasks/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you need a whole separate class for this. I prefer to create these as I need them, on the fly. I think you'll get yourself shoehorned, where you'll use your class in multiple places and then decide you want to do something else in `Workers_Completed` in certain cases, or do something different when an error occurs in certain cases, and that one class *could* end up being a tangled-up pain. That's just my opinion though.

Also, you have to be very careful about touching the UI thread from your BackgroundWorker. In the example below, I'm passing in your node count to the `DoWork` event, instead of having it possibly touch a UI component directly. I'm also passing the list to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, so that you're back in the main thread when it tries to attach the list to your ListView.

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

bw.DoWork += (s, e) =>
  {
    var nodePropertiesCount = (int)e.Argument;

    // the guts of `Discovery` go in here

    e.Result = NetworkedComputers;
  };

bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
  {
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // Task Completed Successfully
        ListView_LocalComputers = (List<DiscoveredComputer>)e.Result;
    }
    else
    {
        // Error Encountered
    }
  };

bw.RunWorkerAsync(Node.Properties.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

SLaks [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20905409/1346943) is correct, but you apparently don't understand what that means. I'd suggest taking the guts of `Discover()` and putting them in the `Workers_DoWork()` method like this:

```
public void Workers_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    GetIcon Icon = new GetIcon();
    BitmapImage IconOfComputer = null;
    List<DiscoveredComputer> NetworkedComputers = new List<DiscoveredComputer>();
    DirectoryEntry Discover = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://Workgroup");
    BitmapImage On = Icon.LoadIcon(@"/Images/Icons/ComputerOn.ico");
    BitmapImage Off = Icon.LoadIcon(@"/Images/Icons/ComputerOff.ico");

    while (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryEntry Node in Discover.Children)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Node.Properties.Count > 0)
                {
                    IconOfComputer = On;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                IconOfComputer = Off;
            }
            if (Node.Name != "Schema") { NetworkedComputers.Add(new DiscoveredComputer { Image = IconOfComputer, ComputerName = Node.Name, MyToolTip = "Node Type = " + Node.SchemaEntry.Name }); }
        }
        break;
    }
    if(backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Result = NetworkedComputers;
    }
}
```

And then modifying your `Workers_Completed()` like this:

```
public void Workers_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Cancelled) { BGW.ThisWorkersResult = "Cancelled By User"; }
  else if (e.Error != null) { BGW.ThisWorkersResult = "Error Encountered: " + e.Error.Message; }
  else
  {
      BGW.ThisWorkersResult = "Task Completed Successfully";
      //BGW.WorkersReturnObject = e.Result;
        //background worker can't touch UI components
        ListView_LocalComputers.ItemsSource = e.Result as List<DiscoveredComputer>;
  }
}
```

I suggest these changes, or something similar, because the background worker can't modify/access UI components (like your ListView), so it has to pass back the value to use for the ListView view its `Result` property. I also included a simple way of detecting cancellation; I'll leave progress reporting up to you to implement.

Comment: I understand this. this is why i seek help from people more knowledgeable. my issue is that i do not want to write three different backgroundworker classes/namespaces for the three different methods i have to run that lockup the UI. there must be a way to parse the method into the DoWork part of the background worker.

Comment: @NewBee I don't understand what you are asking: are there three separate operations you want to perform in a background worker, with this `Discover` operation one of them? If so, you could simply define an enum with a value representing each operation, pass an instance of that enum as the argument to your background worker, and then the background worker could evaluate the enum to figure out which operation to do.

Comment: i have 3 methods that take a long time. 1: enumerates the local computers, 2:Gets Some WMI data of those computers 3: Enumerates the network node hopes to the device (To identify location) do i need to write a background worker for each of these methods to achieve them working in the background and not lock up my UI ?

Comment: In that case, yes, I'd suggest creating three background workers to do each of those tasks, assuming you don't want to do them at the same time (one after the other). If that was the case, then you could do it all in one background worker. You don't need to create classes for this though, look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20905787/1346943).

Comment: oh well thats a bit redundant. the tasks do run at the same time initially. but the user might want to "refresh" the data as such. thank you i will proceed with that.

Comment: @NewBee the way I think of background workers usually is that one is needed for each long-running task I need it for and I would name them as such. So for your situation, I'd have something like `findComputersWorker`, `retrieveWMIWorker`, and `enumerateNetworkHopsWorker`, which breaks it up and makes it obvious what each one does.

Comment: is there a way i can make a new event on the fly. that way i dont have to make all the progress reported and cancelled stuff again ?. im sorry but i just dont understand why i have to write the same piece of code twice

Comment: @NewBee I'd suggest just sucking it up and doing it again, but you could share at least the progress handler between background workers. If you define a more complex return type, you could share the `Completed` handler as well, with that handler first needing to figure out which type of worker is done.